# insert two images in XSL with XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I want to include two images in front of one document. to create that PDF i use XSTL and XML. In this case the XML is:

```
<doc>
    <titulo>
        <![CDATA[ DOCUMENTO DE PRUEBA]]>
    </titulo>
    <img1>D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\MyApp/img/logos/1977__PDF_PORTADA__wDocumento.jpg</img1>
    <img2>D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp4\wtpwebapps\MyApp/img/logos/1977__PDF_PORTADA__wDocumento.jpg</img2>
    <sociedad>SOCIEDAD DE PRUEBA</sociedad>
    <cif>CIF - B12345678</cif>
    <direccion>Gran via</direccion>
    <direccionSec>Castellana</direccionSec>
</doc>
```

When i include only one image, it works.

```
                <fo:table-row height="140mm" display-align="center">
                    <fo:table-cell  > <!-- Celda para Tipo de solicitud -->
                        <fo:block text-align="center">
                            <fo:external-graphic>
                              <xsl:attribute name="src" >
                                <xsl:value-of select="/doc/img1"/>
                              </xsl:attribute>
                      </fo:external-graphic>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
```

But when i include two images it shows nothing.

```
      <fo:table-row height="140mm" display-align="center">
        <fo:table-cell  >
          <!-- Celda para Tipo de solicitud -->
          <fo:block text-align="center">
            <fo:external-graphic>
              <xsl:attribute name="src" >
                <xsl:value-of select="/doc/img1"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </fo:external-graphic>
            <fo:external-graphic>
              <xsl:attribute name="src" >
                <xsl:value-of select="/doc/img2"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </fo:external-graphic>
          </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
```

What im doing wrong?

The full XSL is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:barcode="org.krysalis.barcode4j.xalan.BarcodeExt"
  xmlns:fox="http://xml.apache.org/fop/extensions"
  xmlns:java="java" extension-element-prefixes="java"
  xmlns:lxslt="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"
  xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan">
<!-- Plantilla para generación de NOTA para la AEPD
 Estructura principal del documento:
 -->

<xsl:attribute-set name="lineaHorizontal">
    <xsl:attribute name="leader-pattern">rule</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="rule-thickness">0.4mm</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="leader-length">19.0cm</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="space-before.optimum">1.0mm</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="space-after.optimum">1.0mm</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="color">black</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>


<xsl:output media-type="application/pdf" indent="no" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match ="/">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <!-- Definir layout principal de la pagina -->
  <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="portada_documento"
          page-height="29.7cm"
          page-width="21cm"
          margin-top="1.0cm"
          margin-bottom="1.0cm"
          border-color="rgb(0,0,0)" 
          border-style="solid" 
          border-width="0.5px"
          margin-left="1.0cm"
          margin-right="1.0cm">
      <fo:region-body margin-top="1.8cm" margin-bottom="1.0cm"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>  
  </fo:layout-master-set>
  <!-- Fin definicion layout (formato) de la pagina -->

  <!-- Comienzo de page-sequence. Definimos secuencia de páginas del documento.
  El atributo master-reference indica el layout-master-set que se aplicará para
  cada página. En este caso solo tenemos un master-set ("nota_aepd") 
  -->  
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="portada_documento">
    <!--  Inicio body flow-name="xsl-region-body" indica que los 
    elementos definidos en esta secuencia se pintarán después del header-->
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <!-- Bloque (1) con Tipo de solicitud y "Datos de registro de entrada -->
        <!-- Bloque con una tabla que tendra dos celdas -->
        <fo:block>
            <fo:table padding="2mm" >
                <fo:table-column column-number="1"/>
                <fo:table-body >

                    <fo:table-row height="50mm">
                        <fo:table-cell padding="2mm"  > <!-- Celda para Tipo de solicitud -->
                            <fo:block  font-weight="bold" font-size="35pt" font-family="calibri" text-align="center">
                                <xsl:value-of select="/doc/titulo" />
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>

                    <fo:table-row height="140mm" display-align="center">
                        <fo:table-cell  > <!-- Celda para Tipo de solicitud -->
                            <fo:block text-align="center">
                                <fo:external-graphic>
                                  <xsl:attribute name="src" >
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/doc/img1"/>
                                  </xsl:attribute>
                          </fo:external-graphic>
                          <fo:external-graphic>
                            <xsl:attribute name="src" >
                              <xsl:value-of select="/doc/img2"/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                                </fo:external-graphic>
                            </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>

                    <fo:table-row height="20mm">
                        <fo:table-cell padding="2mm" > <!-- Celda para Tipo de solicitud -->
                            <fo:block text-align="center">
                                <fo:leader xsl:use-attribute-sets="lineaHorizontal"/>
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:block  font-weight="normal" font-size="8pt" font-family="calibri" text-align="justify">                             
                                Texto de prueba y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  
                                <xsl:value-of select="/doc/sociedad" /> 
                                y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  y prueba  
                            </fo:block> 
                            <fo:block text-align="center">
                                <fo:leader xsl:use-attribute-sets="lineaHorizontal"/>
                            </fo:block>                     
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>     

                    <fo:table-row height="20mm" display-align="after">
                        <fo:table-cell padding-left="2mm" >
                            <fo:block  font-weight="normal" font-size="6pt" font-family="calibri" text-align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="/doc/sociedad" />
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:block  font-weight="normal" font-size="6pt" font-family="calibri" text-align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="/doc/cif" />
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:block  font-weight="normal" font-size="6pt" font-family="calibri" text-align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="/doc/direccion" />
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:block  font-weight="normal" font-size="6pt" font-family="calibri" text-align="left">
                                <xsl:value-of select="/doc/direccionSec" />
                            </fo:block>                 
                        </fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row> 

                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:flow>    
    <!-- Fin body --> 
  </fo:page-sequence>
  <!-- Fin page-sequece -->
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't have your graphic, but the FO generated from your XML and stylesheet worked for me with AH Formatter V6.3 with the only error message being about the missing graphic file.  The formatted document shows two of AH Formatter's image that it substitutes for missing graphics.

Comment: I used Apache FOP and substituted two images and it worked fine. I suggest you try with small images and see if the issue is not that the image is too large to fit.

Comment: Do you get any warning / error message? Which version of FOP are you using?

Comment: I used Apace FOP 1.1, no warnings or errors (because I pointed to my own images of course). FYI, it helps to reference my SO handle in your comments as this would put an item in my email box. I only stumbled on your question to me in reviewing something else.